# How to decryption with MCRYPT_ARCFOUR?

Tags: php, encryption, web, mcrypt, rc4-cipher

I am trying to decrypt a text which is encrypted with **ARCFOUR** cipher. But it is not giving me the desire output.

My code:

```
<?php

$key = "25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b";
$data = "B9D6B23709029B47043904AC5F";
$iv = "";
$output = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM,$iv);

echo $output;
?>
```

It is giving me bellow output:

```
`vþ°_¡!YH´@ÃV6P9;EfA
```

But actual output is :

> 9779802100083

I don't know what I am missing.I am using PHP Version 5.5.32 and mcrypt version 2.5.8. Do they support "MCRYPT_ARCFOUR" ? I did some research and found that only mcrypt-2.4.x support  "MCRYPT_ARCFOUR". Is there any way to solve this issue without changing mcrypt-version?

Comment: Trailing `,` after `MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM`.

Comment: [***Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)

Comment: hex decode the arguments.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to hex decode the key and data arguments before doing "ARCFOUR"? @James K Polk

Comment: Yes, that is what he meant.

Comment: But key and data are hex value. @Narf

Comment: They're hex *encoded*, because they're otherwise binary and wouldn't be able to read them ... Just do it, it will work.